# CSS: Placing two different sized elements so that the middle is exactly between them

Tags: css

It's pretty difficult for me to describe what I want, but I'll try (Also see the picture I drew xd). If I have two buttons inside of a `flex-box` that are centered horizontally with `justify-content: center`, it puts the buttons right next to each other and centers them just like it would if they were a single block. However, my buttons don't have the same width, and I would like to have them centered in a way so that the exact middle is between them. Is that easily possible within a `flex-box`, or in some other way?

[image]

Comment: Can you include your HTML and CSS in the question?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!